# Entity Framework 6.1.3 Log SQL queries only if exception occurred On DBContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3. I want to log SQL queries with parameters after only if an exception occurred in the catch block. Is there any way to log queries in this way?

```
try
{
   base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // I want to log SQL queries here.
}
```

Comment: why not just let .Log write to a memory stream and just dump this stream to a log file if you enter the exception block?

Comment: Yes implemented the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logged the log into the memory stream and if the exception has occurred the log is added to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below logging libraries as shown below described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278018/Best-Logging-libraries-for-ASP-NET-MVC).

1. Log4net  (Logging in text file + logging in SQL database)
2. Nlog  (Logging in text file + logging in SQL database)
3. Serilog  (Logging in text file + logging in SQL database)
4. Elmah (logging in SQL database)

Alternatively you can create a procedure to track and insert the log/issue in the database manually as below.

```
try    
 { 
   //Your code here.
 }    
 catch (Exception ex)    
 {        
   ExceptionLogging.SendExcepToDB(ex);    
   Label1.Text = "Some Technical Error occurred,Please visit after some time";     
 }
```

You can get the details from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/logging-exception-to-database/).

Comment: @MaheshBhosale You are welcome and I had already said there are various way to log the exception both from the application and in database side also.